# Width of UITableView Cell not changed when constraints are applied xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard, ios-autolayout

I'm using a custom tableview cell and auto layout but I'm facing the following error, i tried applying different constraints so that the width is stretched but found no success. Could someone please help me on how to adjust the constraints so that the cell fills up the entire width of the screen?

I've tried adding trailing constraints and equal width constraints but didn't get any success

[image]

---

Edit 1:

I tried this based on the suggestions and got this

[image]

And in the preview it's showing me this

[image]

---

Edit 2:

The same error occurs in another layout too

Here it is

[image]

The constraints added are

[image]

And the preview of smaller screen size

[image]

All elements outside of tableview are getting scaled properly, the error is occurring for elements inside tableview, the error being that the width of the cell is not getting adjusted according to the screen size

Could you please help me with this?

---

Edit 3:

Here's the constraints and output with colored background for better understanding, I still found no solution and can't understand why it is not working, could some one please help

Constraints:

[image]

Output in preview window:

[image]

---

Edit 4:

I created a simple layout to make it easier to solve the problem

[image]

And the output

[image]

The main problem is that the width is not scaling, can't seem to understand why...

---

Edit 5:

When I did the same layout on iPhone SE then these were the results, I've used the same constraints as above in Edit 4

[image]

Constraints don't seem to work inside the table view cell. Could some one tell me how this issue could be resolved? Thanks

Comment: can you add code/storyboard screenshot? seems like red box is missing constraints

Comment: Can you please share the constraints that are added to the views?

Comment: I think that the Content Compression resistant priorities for "Title" & "Time" are the ones creating the issue. Can you try giving a fixed width to "Title" and a leading constraint between the two?

Comment: I made a simpler tableview cell with just an UIView, the width doesn't seem to get adjusted with the constraints, I've added it in Edit 4

Comment: @aj_ios could you please help me understand how this issue could be resolved? It's been two days I'm stuck on this bug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your **Edit5**, I believe you are want something like this.

[Edit5 SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUgNP.png)
[Edit5 XR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCSQa.png)

These are the screenshots from XR and SE.
1. Let your cell calculate the height automatically. You just need to apply constraints on the items inside the cell.
2. In the UITableViewCell, add a UIView(background color: Yellow) with constraints top,bottom, leading, trailing equal to 0. Give a fixed height to this view if you dont want it to be equal to default row height.
3. In this yellow UIView, add another UIView(background color: Green) with constraints leading=10, trailing =10. Mark this green UIView "center vertically in container" to it's parent i.e yellow UIView. Now, give green UIView equal height constraint to it's parent i.e yellow UIView. You can change it's multiplier according to your needs.

Constraints on Edit5:
[Edit5 Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQEDS.png)

Moreover, for your **Edit1**, according to my understanding, you are not applying Content Hugging priority to Time label. Content hugging priority comes into play when available content is more than the total size of the content. Here, available content = width of the screen and total size of the content = Title+Time.
So, you need to set Time's Content Hugging priority high and Title's Content Hugging priority low for Title label to expand on your screen. The one with higher priority gets squeezed i.e hugs tightly it's content.

I have attached the screenshot of the screens XR and SE.
[Edit1 SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxPKQ.png)
[Edit1 XR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxvZt.png)

Constraints on Edit1:
[Edit1 Constr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SywIA.png)

Comment: In Edit5, if you dont want to take an extra yellow UIView, you can use Content View of TableViewCell. Give all the green UIView constraints same as above to ContentView this time. Set background color of Content View as yellow. This will save 1 extra view in your cell. Also, you can change the height of green UIview in respect of your content view by giving a multiplier in the height property of green uiview to content view.

Answer (score 1):

First take a UIView on tableviewCell and give leading,trailing,Top,Bottom to 0. and then design your upper view. and don't give any leading to **Time** Label.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If added the views in this hierarchy for the cell, it works fine with all devices.

Please check the constraints added.

Comment: Sure! Will try this. Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried the above solution you've provided but still it's not working.. I've edited the question above and have added the constraints and the output above. Could you please have a look and help me understand what could have been wrong? Thanks

Comment: It's also happening with my another layout

Comment: Can you please try giving a background color to the cell, to ensure that is it the cell which is not increasing in width or there actually is an issue with the constraints?

Comment: Yes I've edited my question 'Edit 3' which includes background color to the views and constraints applied

Comment: I think that the Content Compression resistant priorities for "Title" & "Time" are the ones creating the issue. Can you try giving a fixed width to "Title" and a leading constraint between the two?